# Trouble with computing a Fourier transform

Tags: fourier-analysis

I am able to compute the Fourier transform of the general form `Exp[-Sqrt[t]]` as shown here:

```
FourierTransform[E^(G (-Sqrt[ B^2 F Abs[t]]))/G, t, ω, 
  Assumptions -> 
    {A >= 0, B >= 0, F >= 0, G >= 0, 
     A ∈ Reals, B ∈ Reals, F ∈ Reals, G ∈ Reals, t ∈ Reals}]
```

But when I add a constant into the square root term, `Exp[-Sqrt[const + t]]`, I do not get a result.

```
FourierTransform[E^(G (-Sqrt[A B + B^2 F Abs[t]]))/G, t, ω, 
   Assumptions -> 
     {A >= 0, B >= 0, F >= 0, G >= 0, 
      A ∈ Reals, B ∈ Reals, F ∈ Reals, G ∈ Reals, t ∈ Reals}]
```

I've also attached a screenshot of the outcome below. Does anybody have any suggestions has to how to make the second expression workable? Thanks.

[image]

Comment: it might take longer time as with me

Comment: the second takes so loong i think there's problem

Comment: The explicit assumptions that your constants are real is unnecessary because they are implied by the preceding assumptions involving inequalities.

Comment: even trying this then plug it k in Fourier still dosn't work!



k = FullSimplify[
  ComplexExpand[
   Re[Refine[
     E^(G (-Sqrt[A*B + B^2 F Abs[t]]))/G, {A >= 0, B >= 0, F >= 0, 
      G >= 0, Element[A, Reals], Element[B, Reals], Element[F, Reals],
       Element[G, Reals], Element[t, Reals]
      }]]]]

Comment: it takes so loong